# BitTorrent seeding despite UPnP and NAT-PMP being turned off

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, bittorrent, nat

Using Deluge BitTorrent client and being **behind two NATs** (home router + ISP router), I've **turned off** both **UPnP** and **NAT-PMP** and let it seed one completed torrent, observing the behavior. To my surprise, the client **starts uploading** the torrent to multiple peers (in a few seconds).

I suppose that it is not in the interest of my client to upload the file, at least not that much that it would **actively** contact others and try to send it. Instead, I would assume that it only **passively listens** for incoming connections requesting the file, and thus uploads only on direct demand. Thus, uploading a torrent that is being seeded means somebody has requested it from me. But then, how come the requests reached my client from outside the NATs?

I can surely imagine a successful communication using a common **NAT traversal** technique, like **UDP hole punching**, but this still requires an active cooperation from my client (who should have no idea about the remote peer needing the file, thus being unable to cooperate). So, how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check the source code of a Bittorrent client to know for sure, but since a peer discovers the IPs on the swarm via an outgoing HTTP connection to the tracker, it can then ask the peers via outgoing connections if they need pieces of a file.

> I suppose that it is not in the interest of my client to upload the file

If you are seeding a complete file, you are essentially saying you want this file to propagate over the network (i.e. publisher situation), so it's not farfetched for a developer to ensure that happens by any means necessary.  Furthermore, many trackers insist you maintain a good seed/leech ratio so in reality this is often something that is wanted.

Comment: OK, so I couldn't find any evidence of trackers having the capability of helping peers with the actual connection (e.g. helping with NAT traversal), so it really seems those uploads are initiated by my seeding client as you suggested (I don't see any other option); which is something I would not have guessed. I'll investigate this further and accept your answer if it proves to be the case. Thanks for now.